# Sphinx attribute MIN() and MAX() values

Tags: php, sphinx

I am interested in retrieving the MIN and MAX values of an attribute from a sphinx search (using the PHP client). Is there a simple procedure to achieve this or is SphinxQL really the only way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is simple, you will require adding attribute which contains the value of count on query of sphinx configuration file. You don’t need to put MAX MIN functions on query. Something like the following.

```
Sql_query = SELECT table.A, table.B as ‘values’
FROM table
GROUP BY table

sql_attr_uint   = values
```

On client application form PHP you will have to apply sorting for MAX and MIN value.

```
$sphinx'['sortMode'] = array(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED => 'values DESC’);
$sphinx'['sortMode'] = array(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED => 'values ACS’);
```

I hope this will solve your scenario.